# Regular expression greediness of repeated overlapping pattern

Tags: python, regex

My goal: Find consecutive binary/unary operators and "correct" the spacing in an expression.

Example:

```
a -=b    =>    a -= b      # Only one operator
a -=-b   =>    a -= -b     # Two consecutive operators
a +-b    =>    a + -b      # Two consecutive operators
etc.
```

I'm using Python to test my regular expression with the intention of porting it to Vim.
For now, I just need to figure out how to recognize `-=-` vs. `-=`, as well as `+-`:

What I've tried:

Defining `op = '[\-+=]=?'` or `op = '-=|+|[\-\+=]'` works for recognizing `'-=-'` as `('-=', '-')` and `+-` as `('+', '-')` but they don't work for `'-='` (recognized as `('-', '=')`).

Full demo:

```
op = '[+\-*/%|^&<>=]=?'
re.sub(r'({0}) *({0}) *'.format(op), r'\1 \2 ', 'a -=-b')    # returns 'a -= -b' correctly
re.sub(r'({0}) *({0}) *'.format(op), r'\1 \2', 'a +-b')      # returns 'a + -b' correctly
re.sub(r'({0}) *({0}) *'.format(op), r'\1 \2 ', 'a -=b')     # returns 'a - = b'. Wrong.
```

How can I control this greediness of capture groups?

Answer (score 1):

Replace with single space using `re.sub(pattern, substring, " ")`

Let me know if any test cases fails

```
(?<=[\+\-\%\*\/])(?=[\+\-])|(?<==)(?! )|(?<=[^ \+\-\%\*\/=])(?=[\+\-\%\*\/]|[ ]+)
```

Here is [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uA6iG3/4)

Pattern explanation:

- `(?<=[\+\-\%\*\/])(?=[\+\-])` will match `+, -, %, *, /` followed by `+` or `-`
- `(?<==)(?! )` will match `=` followed by no space
- `(?<=[^ \+\-\%\*\/=])(?=[\+\-\%\*\/])` will match non-operator followed by an operator
- `[ ]+` will match one or more spaces to replace extra spaces with single space

Comment: I admit this works for my example but not for the general problem. For example, it doesn't work for `a +-b`. `+` vs `-=` presents an issue with variable-width pattern in look-behind. I'm sorry, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Let me know if any test cases fails:

Comment: [Here's an updated version with more test cases](http://regex101.com/r/uA6iG3/5). I added a couple operators so that I can extend it once I get it working. You've showed me how to use positive/negative lookahead/behind so I can probably figure it out from here... however it is kind of fun to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r'(\w+)\s*([+\-*/%|^&<>=]=?)([-+]?)\s*(\w+)', r'\1 \2 \3\4', 'expression here')
```

As an example:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'(\w+)\s*([+\-*/%|^&<>=]=?)([-+]?)\s*(\w+)', r'\1 \2 \3\4', 'a -=-b')
print re.sub(r'(\w+)\s*([+\-*/%|^&<>=]=?)([-+]?)\s*(\w+)', r'\1 \2 \3\4', 'a -=b')
print re.sub(r'(\w+)\s*([+\-*/%|^&<>=]=?)([-+]?)\s*(\w+)', r'\1 \2 \3\4', 'a +-b')
```

Output:

```
a -= -b
a -= b
a + -b
```

You can find an online demonstration [here](http://labs.codecademy.com/CVdD#:workspace).

Comment: @user3218114 If it gets beyond two variables, regex is not the way to deal with it.